# Purpose of (void) in a multiple-action change part of a for loop

Tags: c++

The example code for `std::uninitialized_copy` at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy
contains a for loop starting with:

```
  for (; first != last; ++first, (void) ++current)
```

In it, what is the purpose of `(void)`?
It seems to work just fine without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You "have" to do this in generic code because technically the user is allowed to overload the `operator,` for their iterator class to do weird stuff. The cast prevents the overload from being found and applied.

Comment: What does "technically" mean? In what other way is the user *not* allowed to overload the comma operator?

Comment: He is of course always allowed to, but I am not sure whether I would accept that breaking anything in a library I write. (Not that something like that exists. ^^) Same thing as `&` vs. `std::addressof`, for the non-public code I write, I just don't allow all too weird stuff. Of course, the standard library has to.

Comment: Is there any good reason to overload the comma operator at all?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Some libraries (Boost, Eigen?) use it for fancy initialization, esp. in a pre-`std::initializer_list` world. I don't know of any reason to do this for iterators, esp. if it breaks code like the above w/o the `void`.

Answer (score 4):

The standard library algorithms guarantee not to call any user functions beyond those that are part of the algorithm. Without the value-discarding cast, the loop would invoke user-defined overloaded comma operators.

See [LWG issue 2133](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2133) for a discussion.

Comment: WTF. There's no reason to vote your answer down, but is there any way to vote down C++?

Comment: @gnasher729: Sure. Write a paper and send it to WG21.

Comment: Swift 3 is removing the classical for loop from the language. This is an excellent example why.